What is the effect on a LightGBM ranker model of having many groups where all observations have the same target value?
I'm working on a recommender system where users are recomended 5 items at a time.
We build a dataset by saving the 5 items along with feature values and a "relevant" target value (1 if the user clicked the item, 0 otherwise) every time a user sees recommendations.
Here's an example dataset, where group_id identifies items recommended to the same user at the same time:
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
random.seed(42)
num_groups = 200000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["group_id"] = [i for i in range(num_groups) for j in range(5)]
df["feature_1"] = [random.random() for _ in range(5 * num_groups)]
df["feature_2"] = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(5 * num_groups)]
df["rank"] = df.groupby("group_id")["feature_1"].rank(method="dense", ascending=False)
df["relevant"] = (
    ((df["feature_1"] > 0.85) & (df["feature_2"] > 0)) |
    ((df["feature_1"] > 0.75) & (df["rank"] == 1))
).astype(np.int8)
print(df.head(25))

Output:
    group_id  feature_1  feature_2  rank  relevant
0          0   0.639427   0.111289   2.0         0
1          0   0.025011  -0.900384   5.0         0
2          0   0.275029   0.038525   3.0         0
3          0   0.223211  -0.964488   4.0         0
4          0   0.736471  -0.417990   1.0         0
5          1   0.676699  -0.233488   2.0         0
6          1   0.892180   0.249262   1.0         1
7          1   0.086939   0.161480   4.0         0
8          1   0.421922  -0.342533   3.0         0
9          1   0.029797  -0.029662   5.0         0
10         2   0.218638   0.191146   3.0         0
11         2   0.505355  -0.535238   2.0         0
12         2   0.026536  -0.015546   5.0         0
13         2   0.198838  -0.718511   4.0         0
14         2   0.649884  -0.242641   1.0         0
15         3   0.544941  -0.177395   3.0         0
16         3   0.220441  -0.092989   4.0         0
17         3   0.589266   0.725364   2.0         0
18         3   0.809430   0.708449   1.0         1
19         3   0.006499  -0.345884   5.0         0
20         4   0.805819  -0.423633   2.0         0
21         4   0.698139   0.410707   3.0         0
22         4   0.340251   0.171093   4.0         0
23         4   0.155479  -0.453763   5.0         0
24         4   0.957213   0.120602   1.0         1

My idea is to fit a LightGBM ranking model:
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm
t_groups = int(0.8 * num_groups)
X_train = df.loc[df["group_id"] < t_groups, ["feature_1", "feature_2"]]
y_train = df.loc[df["group_id"] < t_groups, "relevant"]
train_group = df.loc[df["group_id"] < t_groups, "group_id"].value_counts().sort_index().to_numpy()
X_valid = df.loc[df["group_id"] >= t_groups, ["feature_1", "feature_2"]]
y_valid = df.loc[df["group_id"] >= t_groups, "relevant"]
valid_group = df.loc[df["group_id"] >= t_groups, "group_id"].value_counts().sort_index().to_numpy()
model = lightgbm.LGBMRanker()
model.fit(
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    group=train_group,
    eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
    eval_group=[valid_group],
)

Many of the groups have relevant == 0 for all 5 observations in the group:
df.groupby("group_id")["relevant"].sum().value_counts()

Output:
1    134866
0     47467
2     16335
3      1278
4        54
Name: relevant, dtype: int64

The same is true of 70% of the groups in my actual dataset. I suspect that while including these groups in the dataset might not harm the model, the data in those groups is useless because the model is unable to distinguish between items in those groups. As a result, the effective size of the dataset is much smaller than the full dataset.
What is the effect on a LightGBM ranker model of having many groups where all observations have the same target value?

The main problem here is your generation process:
The columns are independently generated. This means that the only information that your features hold about the outcome is sampling noise.
Or in short: There cannot be a good model for your exsample
Try to sample first the relevant column.
Then sample the features differently for df['relevant']==0 and df['relevant']==1.
Furthermore, 5 groups / 25 samples are too few to train a proper lightgbm model. If you have a generative process (like the one I described), why not generating 25,000 samples instead of just 25?

Yes, the dataset is trivial, as I mentioned in my question. I was trying to illustrate the basic structure of the dataset, not to generate data suitable for modeling, which I don't think is necessary to understand the question or provide an answer. However, I have edited the question to provide a dataset that is suitable for a LightGBM ranking model. If you have an answer for my question, I would love to see it.

Also, this response does not answer the question and so should have been submitted as a comment instead of an answer.

I agree. I misunderstood the core of your question, which led to this bad answer. My apologies for that.

I will try to answer you question within the next days. Unfortunately this will take some more time (which I currently have little of).
Here a short spoiler: the lamdaRank gradient for groups of uniform relevance will be zero. Many of such groups can lead to lightGBM learning to distinguish uniform from non-uniform relevance groups (if there is a statistical difference between the two). Hence, these groups are not purely useless, but might carry some information.
